# Internet Explorer 11 datalist option text spaces are removed after diacritic character

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

When the suggestion is selected in Internet Explorer 11 all spaces after the diacritic character are removed:

```
<datalist id="test">
  <option>And t&euml;st - me</option>
</datalist>
<input type="text" list="test">
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the option text node, use the value attribute.

```
<datalist id="test">
  <option value="And t&euml;st - me" />
</datalist>
<input type="text" list="test">
```

This is the correct (W3C) way.